# Looping dynamic keys in an object cant seem to get arrays within to output

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently trying to loop through an object, in that object I have a mixture of objects and arrays.

The Object

```
var templateObject = {
    "addressbook": {
        "streetaddress": ["streetaddress1", "1"],
        "country": ["country", "2"]
    },
    "companyname": ["thecompanyname", "1"],
    "email": ["theemail", "1"]
};
```

Looping the object, we won't always know the names of the keys that are in the object, so I'm trying to loop them

```
for(var prop in templateObject)
{
    document.write(prop);
    if(templateObject.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    {
        for(var subItem in templateObject[prop])
        {
            var currentItem = templateObject[prop][subItem];
            document.write('<b>' + currentItem[0] + '</b><br/>');
            document.write(currentItem[1]);        
            document.write('<hr/>');
        }
    }  
}
```

it's currently returning:-

> addressbook  streetaddress1 1 country 2 company name th 1 undefined
>   email t h 1 undefined

I seem to be able to get the addressbook object without any issues, but I can't seem to get companyname or email out and print it to the screen.

I'm hoping someone can help me with this as I've been struggling with this one for a while

I have also prepared a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dimmers/97mqke0f/

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to covert the loop into a function, then if you find a property that's an object, call the function recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Object.keys` function on your object, it is very nice.

Doing `Object.keys(templateObject)` should give you `addressbook`, `companyname`, `email`

Also `var in` is only for objects. It won't work on companyname or email as they are arrays.

This works for me:

```
var templateObject = {
    "addressbook": {
        "streetaddress": ["streetaddress1", "1"],
        "country": ["country", "2"]
    },
    "companyname": ["thecompanyname", "1"],
    "email": ["theemail", "1"]
};


function writeIt(currentItem) {
    // currentItem should be array
    document.write('<b>' + currentItem[0] + '</b><br/>');
    document.write(currentItem[1]);
    document.write('<hr/>');
}

for (var prop in templateObject) {
    document.write(prop);
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(templateObject[prop]) == '[object Object]') {
        for (var subItem in templateObject[prop]) {
            var currentItem = templateObject[prop][subItem];
            writeIt(currentItem);

        }
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(templateObject[prop]) == '[object Array]') {
        writeIt(templateObject[prop]);
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/97mqke0f/1/

Comment: "*[for..in] won't work on companyname or email as they are arrays*". Oops, *for..in* works on arrays (it's handy for sparse arrays) but is not recommended because it may return more than just the indexes and they might not be in order.

Comment: Oh wow thanks for that info @RobG I learned something by providing an answer, I love StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to get the keys, then call it recursively for properties that are objects (i.e. `typeof value == 'object'`). But you might want to not iterate over values that are Arrays, so check using *Array.isArray* first.

e.g.

```js
function showKeys(obj) {

  // Get the keys of object and show them
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  document.write('<br>' + keys.join(', '));

  // Check for values that are Objects, ignore Arrays, and call recursively
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    var value = obj[key];
    if (typeof value == 'object' && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      showKeys(value);
    }
  });
}

var templateObject = {
    "addressbook": {
        "streetaddress": ["streetaddress1", "1"],
        "country": ["country", "2"]
    },
    "companyname": ["thecompanyname", "1"],
    "email": ["theemail", "1"]
};

showKeys(templateObject);
```

This will cope with any depth of nesting, but won't deal with Objects inside Arrays, but it's trivial to get those too (loop over Arrays as well but don't print their keys).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem before, and I wrote a function to solve it. Here is my code, it will loop through a object and output all the enumerable properties.

```js
function joOutput(o, decodeUrl) {
  var txt, depth, sp, sub, isEmpty;
  if (typeof o !== "object")
    return "[Not an object]";
  isEmpty = function(e) {
    var i;
    for (i in e)
      return false;
    return true;
  };
  if (isEmpty(o))
    return "[Empty Object]";
  txt = "<b>NOTE:</b>n for attribute name, d for depth, v for value.<br>";
  txt += "-----------------------------------<br>";
  depth = 0;

  sp = function(n) {
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      s += "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp.";
    }
    return s;
  };
  sub = function(obj) {
    var attr;
    for (attr in obj) {
      if ((typeof obj[attr]) !== "object") {
        if (decodeUrl)
          obj[attr] = decodeURIComponent(obj[attr]);
        txt += sp(depth) + "[n: " + attr + " - d: " + depth + " - v: <b>" + obj[attr] + "</b>]<br>";
      } else {
        txt += sp(depth) + "[n:" + attr + " - d:" + depth + "]...<br>";
        depth++;
        arguments.callee(obj[attr]);
      }
    }
    depth--;
    return txt;
  };
  return sub(o);
}

// Test:
var templateObject = {
    "addressbook": {
        "streetaddress": ["streetaddress1", "1"],
        "country": ["country", "2"]
    },
    "companyname": ["thecompanyname", "1"],
    "email": ["theemail", "1"]
};

var txt = joOutput(templateObject);
document.write(txt);
```